# Elasticsearch error not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (Although I am able to ping its IP)

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to set up an Elastic Search cluster with two nodes but I keep getting this error.

```
[o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [master-node] not enough master nodes discovered ?during pinging (found [[Candidate{node={master-node}{EzeNCWZBR0aAKUP6Va9ZwA}{ZFq4O019Q2WVEWiISBQi2g}{ip-172-31-6-165}{172.31.6.165:9300}{ml.machine_memory=8369979392, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, 
ml.enabled=true}, clusterStateVersion=-1}]], but needed [2]), pinging again
```

Here are my node configuration:

```
1. Master Node
    cluster.name: prod-analytic-stats
     node.name: master-node
     path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
     path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
     network.host: ip-172-31-6-165
     discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ip-172-31-21-37", "ip-172-31-6-165"]
     discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2



2. data node
     cluster.name: prod-analytic-stats
     node.name: replica-node
     path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
     path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
     network.host: ip-172-31-21-37
     discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ip-172-31-21-37", "ip-172-31-6-165"]
     discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

However I am able to ping data node from master node.

```
root@ip-172-31-6-165:/etc/elasticsearch# ping 172.31.21.37
PING 172.31.21.37 (172.31.21.37) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.31.21.37: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.18 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.21.37: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=1.07 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.21.37: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=1.14 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.21.37: icmp_seq=4 ttl=255 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.21.37: icmp_seq=5 ttl=255 time=1.16 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.21.37: icmp_seq=6 ttl=255 time=1.12 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.21.37: icmp_seq=7 ttl=255 time=1.21 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.21.37: icmp_seq=8 ttl=255 time=1.05 ms
--- 172.31.21.37 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.051/1.131/1.219/0.068 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

`discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` must have the same value on all nodes. If you set it to 2 on both nodes, then both nodes must be eligible masters, i.e. `node.master: true`.

If you set it to 1, then only a single node needs to have `node.master: true`.

In your case, you have `minimum_master_nodes: 1` on your data node `ip-172-31-21-37` and `minimum_master_nodes: 2` on your master node `ip-172-31-6-165`, so it's not going to work.

Comment: I changed the configuration of data node as suggested by you. But it still shows the same error and on both the nodes.

**[replica-node] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[Candidate{node={replica-node}{BwXOshm2TvSOlmOWQkbIdA}{pOR8Q3PvR8ORMyYEYJp6Ig}{ip-172-31-21-37}{172.31.21.37:9300}{ml.machine_memory=8364945408, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.enabled=true}, clusterStateVersion=-1}]], but needed [2]), pinging again**

Comment: Issue resolved refer thread here:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-error-not-enough-master-nodes-discovered-during-pinging-although-i-am-able-to-ping-its-ip/148065

Comment: Yes I changed the configuration as well.